# How to resolve permission issue in applet?

Tags: java, permissions, applet

I have one small problem with applet, I got following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at applet.JSGD_Register.jButtonInitActionPerformed(JSGD_Register.java:861)
    at applet.JSGD_Register.access$1(JSGD_Register.java:841)
    at applet.JSGD_Register$2.actionPerformed(JSGD_Register.java:195)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.jnifplib)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at SecuGen.FDxSDK.jni.JFPLib.<clinit>(JFPLib.java:68)
    ... 27 more
```

Why this occurs and how to resolve it?

Comment: http://www.seemoredata.com/en/showthread.php?52-Exception-in-thread-quot-AWT-EventQueue-2-quot-java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError & http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-04.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all read this document - [What Applets Can and Cannot Do? **](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) and decide what kind of code an applet allows. As @AndrewThompson pointed out (*see* comment) that `signed` applets do not have the security `restrictions` because they are `digitally signed` (signature) which proves that they came untampered from a particular trusted author.

For more information about signed applets check out :

1. [Security in Rich Internet Applications](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html)
2. [Understanding Signing and Verification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html)

Comment: The policy tool mentioned in your second link is not suitable for a publicly deployed applet.  For trust in such an applet, it needs to be digitally signed (and OK'd by the user).

Comment: Good edit.  The one thing I think might be slightly misleading is the term 'trusted author'.  A digital certificate can be generated for 'self-signing' code, using an SDK.  This is not a certificate that an average end user should trust, since it was not verified by a Certification Authority like VeriSign.  I can make a self-signed certificate that says I'm me, but it means nothing, since I can also make a certificate that says I'm *you.*  Fortunately, the JVM will not treat verified & self-signed certificates the same.  **Big warnings** come with the self-signed.

Comment: Hello AVD & Andrew, thanks for reply, i appreciated your valuable feedback, here i have to access one .dll library in applet but i cant access and its "jnifplib.dll", but i cant access it and got error as i given in code, so what are the basic step i have to do to resolve this?? i hope you wil be giove  me some basic simple step or suggest me to ractify my mistake to build jar.